# .htaccess redirect unless from certain domain need help allowing search engines and not redirecting as with other visitors

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, referer

I have a tricky one here for the .htaccess guru!

I have a site i.e. mysite.co.uk but i dont want people to be able to go straight to the homepage of mysite.co.uk instead i redirect them to enter.mysite.co.uk a subdomain of mysite.co.uk.

Currently I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://enter.mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://enter.mysite.co.uk [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This does what I want it to but the problem is the redirect is turning away Google bot and all other search engines, so my question is this is there any code I can add to allow a number of the larger search engine bots/spiders to enter without having to have come from the refering url i.e. enter.mysite.co.uk

Help greatly appreciated with this im pulling my hair out and nearly bald now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a negative condition for search bots like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|adsbot-google|bingbot|msnbot|psbot|gigabot|twitterbot|linkedinbot|yahoo-mmcrawler|pingdom\.com_bot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://enter.mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://enter.mysite.co.uk [L,R]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This way your first rule won't be applicable for listed search bots.

Comment: Thankyou so much my friend very good of you to take the time to answer that for me :) I have applied it to my .htaccess and so far so good as the site is functioning fingers crossed search engines will now be able to see my site. Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: any chance you could assist me with another htaccess problem here                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532069/htaccess-to-re-write-incoming-requests-by-inserting-load-after-domain-name

Comment: I provided my answer on your other question.