# .htaccess to re-write incoming requests by inserting "/?load=" after domain name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am in need of some help with coding to rewrite incoming links, this is what I need:

incoming request http://mysite.com/whatever

rewrite to

request http://mysite.com/?load=/whatever

so in a nutshell the incoming links need correcting by adding "/?load=" immediately after the domain name.

The changes are required after making changes to my sites navigation

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /?load=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Place these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?load=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?load=/$1 [L,QSA]
```